# How to convert NSData to an audio file and save it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, core-audio, audiobuffer

How to create `audiofile.aif` and append audio with nsdata?

```
NSData * audioData = [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer->mAudioData length:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize * NUM_BUFFERS];
```

Comment: Is audioData an NSData object containing samples?  If so, what is the format of the samples?  Stereo floats?  Mono SInt16s?

Comment: @dave234 my complete code in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762974/how-to-play-nsdata-audio-buffering-receive-from-web-socket

Comment: The question you linked to is too much work to read through.  Just provide a little more detail here and we’ll get it solved :)

Comment: Find our if the audio is stereo/mono, Int16/floats, interleaved/de-interleaved.

Answer (score 1):

For Convert NSData

```
myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myUrl];  //"audiofile.aif" url
```

Use `NSData` `writeToFile` method for save file.

Try this

```
[myData writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/audio.aif"] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I'm already use this code but  Broken file is created and can't play it.

Comment: Have you set name of file is  "audio.aif " while write  file ?