# how to play audio buffering Via NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, nsdata, audiobuffer

I want to play audio buffering Via NSData :

```
NSData * audioData = [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer->mAudioData length:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize * NUM_BUFFERS];
```

in this code:

```
void AudioInputCallback(void * inUserData,
                        AudioQueueRef inAQ,
                        AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                        const AudioTimeStamp * inStartTime,
                        UInt32 inNumberPacketDescriptions,
                        const AudioStreamPacketDescription * inPacketDescs)
{
    RecordState * recordState = (RecordState*)inUserData;
    if (!recordState->recording)
    {
        printf("Not recording, returning\n");
    }


    printf("Writing buffer %lld\n", recordState->currentPacket);
    OSStatus status = AudioFileWritePackets(recordState->audioFile,
                                            false,
                                            inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                            inPacketDescs,
                                            recordState->currentPacket,
                                            &inNumberPacketDescriptions,
                                            inBuffer->mAudioData);



    if (status == 0)
    {
        recordState->currentPacket += inNumberPacketDescriptions;

        NSData * audioData = [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer->mAudioData length:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize * NUM_BUFFERS];
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? If you are getting some raw data from your input device then you need to know what format these data are in. You should be able to either save/transform them into some format such as mp3 which can then easily be used for playback. If your data is already in such format then it is best to just write them `[audioData writeToFile: [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temporaryFile.mp4"], atomically: YES]` and then use any standard method to play this file.

Comment: @Matic Oblak: I want to create VoIP app. my problem is: I'm not know how to play back audio receive from the web socket(NSData) my code in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762974/how-to-play-nsdata-audio-buffering-receive-from-web-socket

Comment: `NSData` is nothing. It is a wrapper around raw data, a `void*` wrapper if you are familiar with C. It is used only because it is an `NSObject` and may be retained, released and in the end deallocated automatically. The data you receive may be anything and in general "writing" them uses encoding to put them into some nice compact file. In your case these raw data may be LPCM in which case you better search for how to play those. But if you are doing VoIP from scratch I believe your problems are way greater then playing this packet. You need to buffer your audio.

Comment: @Matic Oblak: thanks for your help, can you complete my source code?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762974/how-to-play-nsdata-audio-buffering-receive-from-web-socket